# Can't get div to animate with Skrollr.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, skrollr

I am starting to work with Skrollr.js after doing the Parallax Master Class by ihatetomatoes. I thought I had a grasp on things and have started to create my own parallax site using Skrollr.js as an experiment and I've hit a bit of a wall (been playing with it for two days now!). The animations I have set up on the first div work fine (a simple text transition). On the second div (#slide2bottom-content), I can't seem to make anything happen, regardless of which data- type I use. Is it perhaps an issue with my CSS or a combination of things?

The site is located here: http://cwdphotography.com/bacon/index.html

Here is a portion of my html:

```
<div id="slide1">
            <div id="slide1top"
                data-0="opacity: 1;"
                data-400="opacity: 0;"
            >
                <h2>Bacon ipsum dolor amet drumstick pork short loin tail, venison shoulder corned beef picanha kielbasa pork chop. Pork loin fatback chuck, ribeye venison tail beef bacon.</h2>
            </div>


    </div>

    <div id="slide2">
                <div id="slide2bottom-content"
                    data-0="opacity: 0"
                    data-600="opacity: 0"
                    data-700="opacity: 1"

                >
                    <h1>The Issue</h1>
                    <h3>Are you in need of bacon covered bacon with bacon filling?</h3>
                    <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet drumstick pork short loin tail, venison shoulder corned beef picanha kielbasa pork chop. Pork loin fatback chuck, ribeye venison tail beef bacon.Bacon ipsum dolor amet drumstick pork short loin tail, venison shoulder corned beef picanha kielbasa pork chop. Pork loin fatback chuck, ribeye venison tail beef bacon.Bacon ipsum dolor amet drumstick pork short loin tail, venison shoulder corned beef picanha kielbasa pork chop. Pork loin fatback chuck, ribeye venison tail beef bacon.</p>
                </div>
        </div>
```